# retornar/download pdf do backend para o ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou convertendo um html para pdf, consegui gerar no backend o pdf com submit, mas com ajax não consigo fazer o download do pdf..
Como posso tratar no ajax para baixar?

Codigo:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Export(string htmlContent)
    {
        var htmlToPdf = new HtmlToPdfConverter();

        var pdfContentType = "application/pdf";

        return File(htmlToPdf.GeneratePdf(htmlContent, null), pdfContentType, "TituloArquivo"+ DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss")+".pdf");

    }
```

Comment: Por que usar ajax se o retorno do servidor vai ser um arquivo?

Comment: porque vai ser uma funcionalidade a mais no sistema para algo especifico, e não deve influenciar o app como um todo.. não sei se estou no caminho errado, ou se tem outra forma de fazer..

Comment: Não seria interessante separar esse método? Um onde transforma o html em pdf e outro que faz o download. Ficaria um pouco mais reutilizável. Eu tenho alguns métodos chamando via `ActionResult` com retorno de File, mas são todos feitos em `HTTPGET` com o front-end chamando `window.location.href`. Um método eu gero o pdf e retorna o nome do arquivo pro front e ele com o nome do arquivo faz o download em outro método. Se quiser eu posto esta solução para você.